# Error: cannot read C:/Users/Ahmed/Downloads/omnetpp-5.6.2/tools/win64/home/project/inet4/src/inet/common/INETDefs.msg

Tags: c++, deployment, clang, omnet++, veins

I attempted to execute the omnet++ project but received 3 errors.
as you can see, I copied and pasted the error message below.

I turned the clang preference in an attempt to correct them, but it was unsuccessful.
I'm attempting to execute a project on windows, the project was created originally on Linux.

Please consider assisting me in fixing it.

thank you.

```
02:17:56 \*\*\*\* Incremental Build of configuration release for project RSUDEPLOY \*\*\*\*
make MODE=release all
cd src && /usr/bin/make
make\[1\]: Entering directory '/c/Users/Ahmed/Desktop/RSUDEPLOY/src'
MSGC: vanetsim/routing/vanetrsu/VANETRSU.msg
Error: cannot read C:/Users/Ahmed/Downloads/omnetpp-5.6.2/tools/win64/home/project/inet4/src/inet/common/INETDefs.msg
make\[1\]: Leaving directory '/c/Users/Ahmed/Desktop/RSUDEPLOY/src'
make\[1\]: \*\*\* \[Makefile:140: vanetsim/routing/vanetrsu/VANETRSU_m.h\] Error 1
make: \*\*\* \[Makefile:2: all\] Error 2
"make MODE=release all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.

02:17:56 Build Failed. 3 errors, 0 warnings. (took 576ms)
```

Comment: check that you've included inet as a project reference: `Project->Properties->Project References`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know wehre the `\*\*\*\*` comes from, but you have some directory misconfiguration here. Shell scripts in the mingw environment (which is used by OMNeT++) should use the `\` charactor only for escaping.

`C:/Users/Ahmed/Downloads/omnetpp-5.6.2/tools/win64/home/project/inet4/src/inet/common/INETDefs.msg` is definitely wrong. It thinks that INET is in the tools directory of the omnet installation. Probably the project was improperly confiugred and INET's locations is not correctly specified.

Comment: thank you for the answer, you were right the location was wrong